# Jquery HTML() working on all pages except for one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This scripts pulls the content from an FAQ page and injects it into a modal.

The script works fine on everything, but the cart page, all of the console logs fire, my response returns successfully, but .html() doesn't add the response to the DOM.

```html
<div id="SafetyPolicyModal" class="safety-policy-modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="close-btn" safety-modal-close-btn>&times;</div>
    <div class="content-render-section"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').on('click','[safety-policy-link]',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('1')
      $("#SafetyPolicyModal").css("display", "block");
      console.log('2')
    });

    $(document).on('click','[safety-modal-close-btn]',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#SafetyPolicyModal").css("display", "none");
    });

   
    $.ajax("/pages/safety-liability?view=no-index").then(response => {
      console.log("!!!!!!")
      $(".content-render-section").html(response);
      console.log(response)
      console.log('done')
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `console.log($(".content-render-section"));` would help to determine the length and/or element that's being targeted

Comment: @coll That's what I originally thought as well, but no only 1 -  div.content-render-section
length: 1

Comment: Check the request in your dev tools Network panel. What is the response?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this particular page has multiple elements with class `content-render-section` and the one you want to target is not the first.

Be specific with your selector to target the right one. FYI, you can use jQuery's [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method to make the code simpler

```js
// Target the content-render-section within your modal
$("#SafetyPolicyModal .content-render-section")
  .load("/pages/safety-liability?view=no-index");
```

Comment: console.log($(".content-render-section")) returns a length of 1